# java intersecting 2dobject

Tags: java

So I have made the following game:

The player moves around freely and shoot bullets which bounce off the walls . I am trying to implement auto aiming. I have tried to implement this using lines, which go around the player.

Now what I am having problems with is calculating where the lines intersect with the walls. I am unsure of how to do this.

I can't use getBounds() as the lines are not 2DRectangles. If anyone has any idea on how I can calculate where the lines intersect with a wall, and return that position, it would be very helpful.

Comment: There is no magic here: you just have to do some basic geometry to figure it out.

Comment: @James_D Is there no method that can calculate the intersection between a line and a 2D rectangle? Also, there are 360 lines coming from the tank, and there are many walls in the maze. I don't think calculating the geometry is an option here.

Comment: I've just worked on the same problem for a different application. I guess I missed this part of my geometry class but your going to be using the parametric forms of a line segment. Google "Java segment ray intersection" for some helpful stackoverflow threads

Comment: @Jdman1699 The maze is randomly generated in my application.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do the math here.

Suppose your line has start at `(startX, startY)` and end at `(endX, endY)`. Then using basic grade-school geometry, any point `(x,y)` on the line satisfies the equation

```
(y-startY) / (x-startX) = (endY - startY) / (endX - startX)
```

Of course,

```
(endY - startY) / (endX - startX)
```

is just the slope of the line, so set

```
slope = (endY - startY) / (endX - startX)
```

and then you have

```
(y-startY) / (x-startX) = slope
```

This might be more convenient if you know the starting point (`startX` and `startY` for the line) and the angle, as you can just do `slope = Math.tan(angle)`.

For the example of the intersection with a horizontal wall, all points on the edge of the wall have the same y-coordinate, call it `wallY`. So if `x` is the x-coordinate of the intersection, you have

```
(wallY-startY) / (x-startX) = slope
```

which you can rearrange to

```
x = startX + (wallY-startY) / slope
```

so the intersection point is `(x, wallY)` with `x` as in the last equation.

If the wall is finite (i.e. it has start and end x points), then the check to see if the line actually intersects the wall is simply `x >= wallStartX && x <= wallEndX`, assuming `wallStartX` is the left end of the wall and `wallEndX` the right end.

If the wall is vertical, then the math is basically the same, except you know the `x` coordinate on the wall (say `x = wallX`), and you want to find the `y` coordinate. So just substitute `wallX` for `x` in the first (or fourth) equation and solve for `y`.

If the wall is not horizontal or vertical, then the math is a little more complicated, though not much. (Left as an exercise for the reader.)

Comment: There are many lines and many vertical and horizontal walls that are randomly generated each time. Also sometimes the lines intersect 2 horizontal walls at the same time (one below and one above). Will your method still be applicable?

Comment: Sure, for the wall above, `wallY` will be the y-coordinate of the bottom edge of the wall, and for the wall below `wallY` will be the y-coordinate of the top edge of the wall. For vertical walls repeat the same idea, but you know `wallX` and need to find `y`. Obviously, you can do the computations for each line in a loop, or whatever you need.

Comment: So how would I calculate the equation of the vertical wall. I'm still a bit confused

Comment: @Huz For a vertical wall, you know `x` (call it `wallX`, the x-coordinate of the wall) and you want to find the `y` coordinate of the intersection. So just replace `x` with `wallX` in the first equation and solve for `y`.

Comment: @Huz This looked like fun, so I played with something similar. Results posted as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/james-d/c9447999e6b3b41f4eae77013621e27d). (Not at all complete, but you can move the circle around with the arrow keys, and fire at a random angle by pressing Enter. The "tank" can pass through walls, just didn't implement that part....) The part you are asking about (intersecting a line with a "wall") is implemented in HorizontalWall.java and VerticalWall.java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the well tested [JTS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/) library for doing such things.